# "King size" or "king sized"

Tags: past-tense

I am not sure whether I should be writing "king size" or "king sized" when describing bed sizes. I have given 3 examples below. Please could you help?

> 1. A spacious and luxurious bedroom equipped with a king size bed.
> 2. The double bedroom contains a king sized bed.
> 3. A family suite with a double bedroom containing a king size bed.

Comment: a quick google search will answer this for you.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_size

Comment: 'King size' is more common according to the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=king+size%2Cking+sized&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cking%20size%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cking%20sized%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

The two examples you give look similar yet can have different meanings, "King Size" is an actual measurement for beds, being the second largest standardised (and widely recognised) size. Other common bed sizes are: "Single"; "Three-Quarter"; "Double"; "Queen"; and "Super-King" although this does vary from region to region.

The other example "King Sized" has a different meaning due to the use of the word "sized" which, strictly speaking, means that the bed is sized for a King. This could be interpreted to mean that the bed was specifically designed for a particular King - since not all people are the same size - and, as such, it is not a real unit of measurement. Consider that most people would not have a real reference point for the size of a king.

Long story short: use "King size" when describing the size of the bed.